# Python test a function with a timeout decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, mocking, pytest

So I have a function which calls some API. I used a decorator with a timeout on it using `timeout-decorator` package. Basically it looks like this:

```py
import timeout_decorator
import requests

@timeout_decorator.timeout(seconds=10, use_signals=False, timeout_exception=MyTimeoutException)
def get_from_api(self, url: str, params: Dict):
    requests.get(url=url, params=params)
```

Now I want to create a test which would check whether this decorator works, so if the execution of the body of `get_from_api` will take longer than in my case 10 seconds - an exception will get raised.

The problem is of course I don't want to wait whole 10 seconds + I have to somehow make the body execute for longer than the timeout, to make the exception get raised.

My question here is: is there a lib, or a simple mock technique, to for example make this timeout be e.g. `0.1s` and the body execution time to be e.g. `0.2s`? P.S I don't know if it's that much relevant, but I am using `pytest`

Comment: Why don’t you simply pass a smaller timeout value to the decorator in the test?

Comment: so you want to raise an timeoutexception after the body execution is completed, is that right?

Comment: Looks like you actually want to test the functionality of the decorator - in this case I would just do this separately (you could just use a `sleep` call as the function body to be tested), and rely on that while testing the rest of the functionality.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen thats what I ended up doing. Dunno if I should make it an answer

Comment: Well, it doesn't actually answer the specific question, so I guess no... though it's up to you.